# Confirmation prompt for change to value on an Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to revert back to the original value if, at the `MsgBox` prompt, the user chooses "No". However, this is not happening. Can you please have a look to see where I am going wrong?

```
Private Sub txtNov2_AfterUpdate()
Dim x As Integer
Dim NewValue As Integer
Dim OrigValue As Integer
NewValue = Me.txtNov2.Value
OrigValue = [Forms]![DataEntry]![txtNov2].OldValue 'Me.txtNov2.OldValue
If NewValue <> OrigValue Then
    x = MsgBox("Value Has Changed Do you Want to Update?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Value Change")
    If x = vbYes Then
        MsgBox ("Please Press Update Button")
        btnUpdateData2.SetFocus
    Else
        txtNov2.SetFocus
        'Me.Undo
        txtNov2.Value = OrigValue
        'Cancel = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that your code is working, as far as it goes. I open the form...

[image: original]

...and change the value from `123` to `124`...

[image: changed]

...then when I hit the [Tab] key so the control loses the focus I get the `MsgBox`...

[image: msgbox]

...and if I choose "No" then the value reverts to `123`

[image: reverted]

The only difference between that state and the initial state (when I first opened the form) is that the form is still "dirty", as indicated by the "pencil" icon in the record selector on the left side of the form. If you want to *completely* undo all changes to the form then try replacing...

```
Else
    txtNov2.SetFocus
    'Me.Undo
    txtNov2.Value = OrigValue
    'Cancel = True
End If
```

...with...

```
Else
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Gord, Only problem now is that when I run it with DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo it gives me a run time error 2046 >> 'the command or action 'Undo' Isn't available now' ...

Comment: @user1775842 I dunno, it works for me, but then my form is extremely simple (one text box and an "Update" button that doesn't actually do anything). Is your form bound to a table/query, and is `txtNov2` bound to a field? (That's the setup that I used.)

Comment: yes it is ... I'll chk to see if I disabled something on the Form control ... sigh.... thx once again for your tip

Comment: I used the List box GotFocus event to reset the values back to the original if there is no change. Thx for pointing me in the right direction.